restoring default fieldset behavior with inline css
My company is using https://tabler.io/ CSS and it's kinda mucking up fieldsets. eg.:


<fieldset>
  <legend>Demo</legend>
  Field 1: <input type="text"><br>
  Field 2: <input type="text">
</fieldset>



This is how that fieldset appears without tabler.io mucking things up:

Here's how it looks like with tabler.io (JSFiddle) :


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tabler/core@1.0.0-beta17/dist/js/tabler.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tabler/core@1.0.0-beta17/dist/css/tabler.min.css">

<fieldset>
  <legend>Demo</legend>
  Field 1: <input type="text"><br>
  Field 2: <input type="text">
</fieldset>




Unfortunately, it's not clear to me how to restore the default behavior with inline CSS
I can get the border to reappear by adding style="border: 1px solid" to <fieldset> but idk how to make the word "Demo" appear inline.
Any ideas?

The browser devtools inspect will show you exactly what CSS is being applied to fieldset, legend and the related input. Set each of those properties to revert and you get back to the standard behavior.

@AHaworth - tried that without success. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsG7UdEUUts . Obviously some CSS attributes can be eliminated. It's hard to see how "color" would result in the behavior that you see. Likewise it's hard to imagine how CSS attributes for any input elements would change how the legend element is being displayed. If it's so easy to use the browser devtools to find it than maybe you should make a video of you using it to find the answer. The proof is in the pudding, after all, eh?

I looked at the video. You are failing to clear the fieldset settings (which occur twice) and I don't see 'revert' anywhere.

As per comment, the browser devtools inspect facility shows the CSS properties set by tabler.
This snippet sets them all to 'revert' so you should be back to the basis from which you can of course add your own styling if wanted:


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tabler/core@1.0.0-beta17/dist/js/tabler.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tabler/core@1.0.0-beta17/dist/css/tabler.min.css">
<style>
  /* the styles as I saw them */
  
  fieldset {
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  
  legend {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: inherit;
  }
  /* now setting them to revert */
  
  fieldset {
    min-width: revert;
    padding: revert;
    margin: revert;
    border: revert;
  }
  
  legend {
    float: revert;
    width: revert;
    padding: revert;
    margin-bottom: revert;
    font-size: revert;
    line-height: revert;
  }
</style>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Demo</legend>
  Field 1: <input type="text"><br> Field 2: <input type="text">
</fieldset>



